# Self mytableView not required

Tags: objective-c, syntax

```
[[self myTableView]setDelegate:self];
```

i understand that using a colon delegate of myTableView is being set to self. (self is the view controller )
but i don't understand the [self myTableView] meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[self myTableView] or self.myTableView is referring to an object that has been defined as a property of self. As you state, self being the view controller in this instance. So somewhere in you classes .h or .m have you got a property definition similar to:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
```

if the table is created in Interface Builder and linked - Or

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *myTableView;
```

If it's a table view created and manipulated programatically in the code.

These properties are [self myTableView] (or self.myTableView)

Answer (score 1):

```
[self myTableView] is equivalent to `self.myTableView`
```

the first one sends message to myTableView, and the last one is the dot notation.